# <script runat="server"> vs. code-behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, runatserver

Are there any caching/performance/significant differences between c# code placed in `<script runat='server'></script>` as oppose in the code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no performance difference, in the end this is always compiled to an assembly anyway.

Comment: There seems to be a difference. Compilation errors within the <script runat="server"/> tag are caught not when the project compiles but when it gets hit at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No, it gets compiled to the same thing.

I suggest you use the code-behind file, in order to separate logic and markup.

Answer (score 1):

The number one significant difference to me is readability.